# Equivalence relation for equidistant points in the plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let an equivalence relation $R$ on the plane be:

$(a,b)\in R$ if $a$ and $b$ are equidistant from the origin.

Well, $(a,a)\in R$ and also, $(a,b)\in R$ means $a$ and $b$ have the same distance from the origin, let's call it $d$. Also, if $(b,c)\in R$, then the distance of $b$ and $c$ from the origin is $d$. We then have $(a,c)\in R$

Now, when I think about the equivalence classes for a point $a$, it's the collection of all points equidistant from $a$ by the origin. Thinking about this, what's the collection of all possible equivalence classes? If I pick a point in the plane, its equivalence class will be the circunference around it. Since I can pick any point, the collection of all equivalence classes would be all the circunferences around all points? So, the equivalence classes would be the entire plane?

Comment: The equivalence classes are just concentric circles about the origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to think of the equivalence classes as being circles of a given radius $r\geq 0$ centered at the origin. Thus there are uncountably many equivalence classes (one for each non-negative real number).

Any equivalence relation on the plane will partition the plane (and conversely).  Thus thinking about all of the equivalence classes unioned together isn't terribly effective.